# Using Angular 'ng-click' with 'ng-repeat' to create dynamic links

Tags: angularjs

I have a set up where I am trying to use my JSON object to create the URL strings in an ng-repeat. The text is viewable when inspected in the broswer, yet it doesn't work, or console log an error.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects">
  <div ng-click="go('/projects/{{project.url}}')"></div>
</div>
```

I parse the $location service in to my controller, and then use the following to change the page url (please note, I have checked this works using non-dynamic URLs in the view):

```
$scope.go = function (path) {
  $location.path(path);
};
```

An example of the JSON object I am using, looks like this:

```
$scope.projects = [
  {
    url: 'paul-davis'
  }
];
```

Comment: Remove the curly braces from project.url -- you're already writing in angular code within an ng-click (I think anyways, removed the answer until I'm sure)

Comment: Sorry, that just puts 'project.url' at the end of the URL string.

Comment: Weird...you shouldn't need to use `{{}}`...waaait, try this (removing some quotes) :: `ng-click="go('/projects/'project.url)"`

Comment: Does the method `go` get called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code within `ng-click` is angular script, not template code to use `{{...}}`. Use it as:

```
<div ng-click="go('/projects/' + project.url)"></div>
```

Comment: what about when you have the ng-click that accesses a method in the controller like <div ng-click="doMethod({{ myObject.id}})" >asdfasdf<div>?

I just cannot get this to work... its driving me nuts!

Comment: for anyone else... you dont need to use `{{var}}` inside of the `ng-click`

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `<a>` tag with dynamic href inside of the `ng-repeat`, it works just as you'd expect - though using  `ng-href` is better, so your links dont break before the data bindings are ready.
you can have a look to this Angular tuto 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref